# Using autofocus in IE

Tags: html, autofocus

I am a newbie in html and I m trying to set autofocus on an input text field...

But this is not supported in IE... is it possible to use JS in order to solve this problem?

Comment: You can use `document.getElementById('field').focus()`

Answer (score 2):

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('elemID').focus();
```

jQuery:

```
$('selector').focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" id="aaa">
<script> 
    window.onload=function(){
        document.getElementById('aaa').focus();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this with javascript

e.g.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function formfocus() {
      document.getElementById('element').focus();
   }
   window.onload = formfocus;
</script>
```

Where 'element' is the id of your html input.